# Offload CPU heavy Promise tasks in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, promise, cpu, worker

I have a series of Promises that I would like to offload to a worker of some sort. But all workers I tried requires a single-thread function (werker, worker-farm, etc)

What is the general approach when it comes to handling CPU intensive function that returns Promises in NodeJS?

Comment: How can a promise be cpu intensive? I assume you mean the work that the promise does instead. at which point you can remove promises from the question as they'd be irrelevant.

Comment: @KevinB The promise itself is not intensive (...) but the CPU-intensive code is based on nextTick loops etc that always returns promises.

Comment: According to the docs, [werker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/werker) *does* support asynchronous functions.

Comment: Child process running a specialized node.js application to do your processing OR clustering to just run multiple versions of your main server so each can be chunking away on CPU intensive things separately.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is single threaded. It always has been. If you have a CPU intensive task, it's going to take a while, and it will block anything else.

To combat that, you need more threads, and that means more processes (single-process = single-thread).

Using multiple processes of the same application is generally useful where each is independent and takes the load off of a work queue or handling load-balanced requests.

Using a child process that is attached to a specific parent, for a specific task is generally useful to offload processing that the parent requires. That is also easier to design.

Answer (score 0):

There is new library called vblaze. Which allows to run parallel task by running nanoJobs. Its an interesting library utilizing worker threads in nodejs .

Run any part of the code parallely among the available threads.
NanoJobs are like go routines in go language if you are aware of it.

Check this link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/vblaze

This has a good documentation .

It also allows to create workers and connect to message brokers like rabbitmq and redis , allowing to processing messages at high throughput.

Comment: For any future viewers, @rranj is actually the author of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Before answering the question let’s make something clear.

> **Promises are made for handling long running tasks (waiting tasks) and not CPU intensive tasks**

I know it doesn’t make sense at first. Let’s take this example

Hotel and the waiter Example:

**Case 1:**

Say a hotel has 5 customers and 1 waiter and 1 chef

Task of the waiter (long running task) : Take menu from customer and deliver the food made by chef

> **Synchronous task:** The waiter attends first customer → Delivers the
> menu to the chef to cook → Waits for the chef to cook → Delivers the
> food to first customer → The waiter attends second customer → and
> cycle repeats
>
> **Asynchronous Task :** The waiter attends first customer → Delivers the
> menu to the chef to cook → Doesn’t wait for the chef → The waiter
> attends second customer → Delivers the menu to the chef to cook →
> Delivers the food to first customer (provided if the chef has finished
> cooking by that time) → cycle continues…

So a waiter’s synchronous task can be converted into asynchronous task easily which is similar to Promises converting long running synchronous task to asynchronous

**Case 2:**

Say a hotel has 5 customers and 1 waiter (waiter should also do the cooking) and no chef

*Note: Once the waiter enters the kitchen, he cannot comeback. He can comeback only after finishing the dishes.*

Task of the waiter : Take menu from customer, cook the food and deliver the food (long running and CPU intensive task)

> **Synchronous task:** The waiter attends first customer  → Cooks the food
> on his own → Delivers the food to first customer → The waiter attends
> second customer → Cooks the food on his own → Delivers the food to
> second customer
>
> **Asynchronous Task :** ????

Can you convert it to asynchronous?? Not possible isn’t it ?

In such case the only way to make it asynchronous is by recruiting another waiters for each customer (new threads)

**Conclusion**

Promises are efficient when you have to wait for someone else to do the heavy task like Database calls, API calls and just deliver the results after it is complete (Such tasks are done outside the event loop thread and notifies event loop when complete)

Promises are not going to be efficient and still blocks when you yourself have to do the heavy task like machine learning algo, mathematical tasks (Such tasks use the same thread as of the event loop and thus continue to block them anyways)

You can use

1. Clustering
2. Worker threads

Answer (score 0):

We should always try to avoid CPU-intensive tasks in the API process. We can use any message broker (example: [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)) to queue in the task and special worker processes subscribed to the queue for executing the tasks.

If the above is not possible or is too much of infra, then you should make use of [child processes](https://plgworks.com/blog/child-processes-using-node-js/). Refer to the [node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) on child processes.